# Pandas-datareader does not show yesterday's stock price data when using Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

The following code produces a dataframe which never shows historical data for yesterday, only up to the day before yesterday. If I switch from 'yahoo' to 'google' it works as expected. (However, since Google has limitations on the number of requests, I have to use Yahoo.) Tested in Jupyter notebooks and the console both on Windows 10 using Anaconda 4.2.3 and on Ubuntu 16.04 (with its included python environment), same result on both machines. pandas_datareader version is 0.2.1 (current as of January 5 2017). What am I missing here?

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.date(2016, 12, 27)
end = datetime.date.today()

df = web.DataReader('AA', 'yahoo', start, end)

df
```

Comment: just now verified your code and looks fine, I do see historic price for Jan 05 when passing the parameters as start = datetime.date(2016, 12, 27)
end = datetime.date(2017, 01, 05).

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why but one day later everything was back to normal. I did not restart either of the two systems, didn't make any updates or code changes but got the correct result regardless of which provider (Google/Yahoo) I chose. Not sure what to do with this question, what's the recommended course of action?